# When do changes to metadata impact a Workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, infopath

If I have a checkbox column for metadata and that checkbox is unchecked when the workflow starts, but is checked at some point during the workflow running, when will the workflow be able to realize that the checkbox has updated?
Does a `wait` or `pause` action need to occur?

Comment: It won't, it starts with the "begin" data and doesn't refresh while running. You could make your workflow fire with an on change. Then read out your checkbox

Comment: @user3328306 if this was the case, wouldn't the `wait` action not actually work?

Comment: No because the workflow is already started and it doens't "see" new changes

Comment: You can start 2 workflows.. 1 the current you have and 2nd the one with a  wait, which will trigger onchange. That would work.